# Find expressions and stock keywords in a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying parse variables and the intervals in which they live in from a file. For example, an input file might contain something like this:

Constants

```
 x1 = 1;
```

Variables

```
x45 in [-45,5844];

x63 in [0,456];

x41 in [45, 1.e8]; #Where 1.e8 stands for 10^8
```

All I want to do is to stock every couple (variable, interval) in a dictionary. If it's a constant, the interval would be [constant, constant]. I first imagined I had to use the built-in function findall to search through the whole file all the lines of the type "x"random_number" in "random_interval" or "x"random_number = random_number" but I don't know how to get and stock the "x" and the intervals after I find all the lines I wanted.

Also, whenever there is a "1.e8" in an interval, I want to replace it by a "10^8" before stocking it in the dictionary.

Any clue ?

Thanks for helping me to solve my problem

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? It might help to show your previous attempts so that people can better answer your question. I would also recommend giving an example output that you are trying to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't exactly know how to begin. All I did is this :

```
from sys import argv
import re

script, filename = argv
#The file which contains the variables is filename, so that I can use as a command 
in a terminal : "python myscript.py filename.txt"

file_data = open(filename, 'r')
Dict = {} #The dictionnary in which I want to store the variables and the intervals
txt = file_data.read()  

#Here I thought I might use this : re.findall(.*"in".*, txt) or something like that 
#but It will get me all the lines of the type "blabla in bloblo".
#I want also blabla and bloblo so that I can put them into my dictionnary like this : 
#Dict[blabla] = bloblo
#In the dictionnary it will be for example Dict = {x45 : [-10, 456]}

file_data.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer Akilan,

if the file is the following :

```
Constants
x1 = 5;

Variables
x56 in [3,12];
x78 in [1,4];
```

It should return the following :

```
{"x1" : [5,5], "x56" : [3,12], "x78" : [1,4]}
```